# Call method from another class in OnClick

Tags: android

I have a class that contains:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View createView) {
    switch (createView.getId()) {
    case R.id.save_button:
        Appointments add = new Appointments();
        add.addAppointment(TITLE);
        add.addAppointment(TIME);           
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to call the addAppointment method which is in another class:

```
 public void addAppointment(String string) {
  // Insert a new record into the Appointment data source.
  // You would do something similar for delete and update.
  SQLiteDatabase db = events.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(TITLE, string);
  values.put(TIME, string);
  db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
 }
```

I have tried this way, but when I click the onclick , the program crashes

Comment: What does the logcat show and why are you trying to call that method twice instead of changing the parameters it takes and send both at once?

Comment: @codeMagic How would I call it once? Shall I just create that method inside the onclick

Comment: No, don't create a method inside the `onClick()`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View createView) {
    switch (createView.getId()) {
    case R.id.save_button:
        Appointments add = new Appointments();
        add.addAppointment(TITLE, TIME);  //Send both together
        break;
    }
}
I want to be able to call the addAppointment method which is in another class:

 public void addAppointment(String title, String time) {  // Change method header to accept both Strings here
  // Insert a new record into the Appointment data source.
  // You would do something similar for delete and update.
  SQLiteDatabase db = events.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put("title", title);   // second param is what you passed in for first param of method
  values.put("time", time);    // second param here is whatever you passed in for second param of method
  db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
 }
```

I don't know what TITLE and TIME are because I don't see them declared or initialized anywhere but inside the `vaules.put()` should be `(key, value)` so you make the `key` something descriptive about the `value` and the `value` obviously just that. Normally all caps represent a `constant` so just something to think about to keep up with standards

Comment: When I try this it gives an error for the values.put(TITLE, string) saying "string cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hopefully that makes it a little more clear

Comment: What does the logcat say when it crashes? If its similar then I can help you. If its a completely different problem then accept this answer and post a new question if you still need help

Comment: quick question. As from the code above. I have an edittext for example and i store whatever is enetered into that edittext into a string. Can I then place that string into the second parameter of values.put("title", title)?
thanks

Comment: Yes, as long as that method has access to it...meaning it has the proper scope, member variable or local to that method but probably a member variable if its an edittext

Answer (score 1):

write method with two parameters 1st.calling method one after other with one parameter won't give you both values.

```
 add.addAppointment(TITLE,TIME);
```